# How to send post request along with data in raw form in Retrofit?

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

[image]

I want to send a data in the above format in raw form of Body. The data type should be "JSON(application/json)" and the header should include "application/json" as Content-Type.

I tried using this way but is not working for me.

```
public interface AddData {
    @POST("/Api/")
    Call<String> postData(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,@Body JSONObject body);
}
```

Comment: what's the error/logcat message?

Comment: I am getting response.isSuccessful() true but the data is not getting updated. When I post the same data through PostMan the data gets updated.

Comment: please share the response from postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Header as the annotations

`@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/Api/")
    Call<String> getUser(@Body JSONObject body);`

Refer to https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1587